# How can I execute the specific line I just printed in zsh?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

Say I have searched the path for some files with mdfind. Now I have several addresses printed and what I want to do is cd into the first address. Is there any way writing a shell script or some thing that could facilitate me getting into the path I want without copy and paste?

```
xxx@MacBook-Pro ~ mdfind -name "adapters.py"
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/libexec/pip/build/lib/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/libexec/pip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.pyc
```

Comment: Not without re-running the command; the shell doesn't store the output of the previous command anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way would be nesting command substitutions

```
cd $(dirname $(mdfind -name "adapters.py" | head -n 1))
```

A function could also define in your `.zshrc`

```
func mdcd() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then return 64; fi
    1=$(mdfind -name "$1" | head -n 1)
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then return 66; fi
    cd $(dirname "$1")
}
```